# Backbone.Model.save and promises

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, promise

I have a Backbone model, when i perform a `model.save()` i get back a promise. My question is what do these promises yield to the done and fail callbacks?

what is 'value' here in both cases? (for the done and fail callbacks)

```
model.save().done(function(value) { });

model.save().fail(function(value) { });
```

Comment: I believe you will get a object in return. You can use the responseText parameter of the object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Backbone documentation says that `.save()` returns a jQuery [jqXHR object](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR), in which case the arguments are :

- **jqXHR.done**: (data, textStatus, jqXHR)
- **jqXHR.fail**: (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)